# Keto diet and mouth odor

Tags: nutrition, diet, ketosis, halitosis-bad-breath

### Background Information

My boyfriend recently started the ketogenic diet about 3 weeks ago and I have started noticing that his breath has been getting stronger and stronger.

It smells like a cross between the purple Listerine and the smell you get when you have a cavity. I read that his body is producing keto bodies - hence the smell.
I also read that it should smell like acetone but this smell is stronger and off-putting/ He brushes regularly now but the odor is still there.

### Question

Can anyone explain to me what is going on, if they have had any experience with this, what they did, or suggest what I can do to alleviate the situation or tell him to him so he can do something about it. I will also appreciate if someone can explain the science behind it.

Comment: I'll write an answer later if I have more time. Just one question: Why was the ketogenic diet chosen?

Comment: @Narusan For weight loss and to be leaner. He also wanted constant energy throughout the day as he complained of fluctuating energy levels throughout the day when he ate carbs. He is also 5'9 and 175ibs just to put things into perspective.

Comment: Are we talking about the [same diet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketogenic_diet) or is he undergoing something like [Atkins diet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atkins_diet)?. Maybe you could link where he gets the dietary requirements for his diet from. There are many similar diets...

Comment: There is *the* ketogenic diet and then there are diets which attempt to get you into a state called *ketosis*.

Comment: @Narusan, It is a ketogenic diet. mostly/high fat diet and proteins and eats less than 30g of carbohydrates a day. He also has Keto sticks which shows that he has transitioned into ketosis per the darker color.

Comment: "Dragon breath" is a fairly common symptom when people start LCHF or similar diets. The recommendations I could find at the time I tried it were parsley and time. The latter worked better but until then, chewing parsley vaguely like you would chew gum brought some relief